# Sort a varchar type column (Alphanumeric Values)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

In my table `VARCHAR` data type column called `CartonNo`, that contain either numbers or number with letter it depends on. I want it to be sorted numerically, this would be an acceptable ascending sort order.

- Issue No. 1

For example, contains like following data

```
1-2
1
3-5
6
1-2A
6-12
7-8
9-12D
9-12
17
9-12B
19
20-30
15-18
```

Now I want to order the data as below

```
1
1-2
1-2A
3-5
6
6-12
7-8
9-12
9-12B
9-12D
15-18
17
19
20-30
```

- Issue No. 2

the bellow value How to sort alphanumeric?

PT15-8-2

PT15-12-10

PT15-12-3

PT15-12-572-575

PT15-12-31

PT11-96

PT11-133-36

PT11-133

PT16-136

PT8-644

PT09-655

PT9-655

PT12-752

PT14-752

PT13-752

PT14-753

PT10-778

PT13-977-978

PT13-979-988

Can anyone please tell me how should I write the query?

Comment: is before `-` value would always intger

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: Some time Only one digit coming at the time getting error such as "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." Please anyone help me... Examplle 1-2, 3-5, 2, 3-5A, 1-2A

Comment: Is there any validation to check sorting value is integer or varchar value.

Comment: FYI: I filed a Microsoft Connect suggestion that this type of sorting be available natively, just as it is in C++: [Support "natural sorting" / DIGITSASNUMBERS as a Collation option](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2932336/support-natural-sorting-digitsasnumbers-as-a-collation-option). Voting for it won't guarantee that they implement it, but it does help indicate how much people actually want that feature :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am assuming before `-` you would have `integer` value always

```
declare @temp table
(val nvarchar(99))
insert into @temp values ('1-2'  )
insert into @temp values ('3-5'  )
insert into @temp values ('1-2A')
insert into @temp values ('6-12')
insert into @temp values ('6-7')
insert into @temp values ('6-12D')
insert into @temp values ('20-30')
insert into @temp values ('15-18')
--insert into @temp values ('3')
--insert into @temp values ('53')
```

QUERY

```
select * from @temp
order by CAST(LEFT(val,CHARINDEX('-',val)-1)  AS INT)
```

Exactly Ordered

```
select * from @temp
order by CAST(LEFT(val,CHARINDEX('-',val)-1)  AS INT)
,CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(val,LEN(val)-CHARINDEX('-',val)), patindex('%[^0-9]%', RIGHT(val,LEN(val)-CHARINDEX('-',val))+'.') - 1)  AS INT),
RIGHT(val,LEN(val)-CHARINDEX('-',val))
```

after run second query the output would be

[image]

**UPDATE** AFTER COMMENT: *sometime varchar val won't come (3-5) or (1-12A) instead of whole number 3 or 5... at the time the above answer getting an error... how to correct way to sort.*

```
-- DECLARE TABLE
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(val nvarchar(99))

--INSERT INTO TABLE
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES 
('1-2'), ('1'), ('3-5'), ('6'), ('1-2A'), ('6-12'), ('7-8'), ('9-12D'), ('9-12'), ('17'), ('9-12B'), ('19'), ('20-30'), ('15-18')

-- QUERY
SELECT * FROM @temp
ORDER BY
CASE 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(val) = 0 THEN CAST(LEFT(val,CHARINDEX('-',val)-1)  AS INT)
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(val) = 0 THEN CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(val,LEN(val)-CHARINDEX('-',val)), patindex('%[^0-9]%', RIGHT(val,LEN(val)-CHARINDEX('-',val))+'.') - 1)  AS INT)
    ELSE val 
    END ,val
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: I'd be careful with this, since you're storing "numbers" in a string column, there is nothing to stop someone from doing this: `insert @temp values('6A-12');` - so, you need to test that substring before blindly converting it to an integer. The best thing to do would be to split it up instead of storing them together; validation can happen at insert/update time, and you can always easily make a computed column that performs the concatenation.

Comment: @tinka thanks alot.. you save my day. another think i want to know how did u get the answer.. can you explain the answered query.. is there anyway or techniques to generate queries...

Comment: @user1663855 nothing any special just try to separate each part and apply as per my understanding of SQL

Comment: @user1663855 Please remove your obsolete comments from this thread. Comments are meant to be temporary post-it-notes, that should be removed once they are addressed.

Comment: @tinka your sort order is correct but one issue such as "Error converting data type varchar to int." please check the 2nd issue in the question i have modified and added the sorting order part i want...thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY LEN(column1), column1,LEN(column2), column2,LEN(column3), column3` usually works for me for the generic case of "sorting alphanumeric values by numeric sorting".

You can order by as many columns as you want

Answer (score -5):

Sorry for that

I think below query is fine for that

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY cast(CartonNo as decimal(38,10)) asc;
```